# Very Slow Query Execution Time

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I’m trying to figure out why the query is taking too long to execute on the server when compared to my laptop. Both the server and laptop are running MySQL 5.1.36 on WAMP 2.0 and have the same database schema, as I have exported it from the server database and imported it into the laptop’s database. It takes `0.031` seconds to execute on the laptop while `82.447` seconds to execute on the server!

Laptop Specifications

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional,
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4600M Processor (4M Cache, up to 3.60 GHz),
Memory: 8GB

Server Specifications

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 2008 Standard SP2,
Processor: Intel® Xeon® Processor X5570 (8M Cache, 2.93 GHz, 6.40 GT/s Intel® QPI),
Memory: 4GB

Here are screenshots of the CPU utilization on the server of when the [query is being executed](https://i.imgur.com/x8G6Ynb.png) and [when not](http://i.imgur.com/WnUTIur.png). Bear in mind, that the server is a VM running in a server farm.

Below is the query and the each table has no more than 1000 rows.

```
SELECT form.id                                                                                  AS `Reference No.`, 
       DATE_FORMAT(form.sbmt, '%d %b %Y')                                                       AS `Submission Date`, 
       DATE_FORMAT(form.sbmt, '%h:%i %p')                                                       AS `Submission Time`, 
       department.name                                                                          AS `Department`,
       section.name                                                                             AS `Section`,
       reporting_to_1.id                                                                        AS `Reporting To 1 - System ID`, 
       reporting_to_1.name_ldap                                                                 AS `Reporting To 1 - Name`, 
       reporting_to_1_department.name                                                           AS `Reporting To 1 - Department`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(reporting_to_2.id, '') USING utf8)                                        AS `Reporting To 2 - System ID`, 
       IFNULL(reporting_to_2.name_ldap, '')                                                     AS `Reporting To 2 - Name`, 
       IFNULL(reporting_to_2_department.name, '')                                               AS `Reporting To 2 - Department`, 
       form_type.des                                                                            AS `Form Type`, 
       CONVERT(IF(form.subno = 0, '-', form.subno) USING utf8)                                  AS `Subscriber No.`, 
       form.subname                                                                             AS `Subscriber Name`, 
       form.incidentdate                                                                        AS `Incident Date`, 
       form.rsndes                                                                              AS `Reason`,
       form.amount                                                                              AS `Amount`,
       form.des                                                                                 AS `Description`,
       CONCAT('http://cns/attach/', attachment_1.path, '/', attachment_1.filename_generated)    AS `Attachment - 1`, 
       CONCAT('http://cns/attach/', attachment_2.path, '/', attachment_2.filename_generated)    AS `Attachment - 2`, 
       IFNULL(info.name, '')                                                                    AS `Agent Info - Name`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(info.emp_id, '') USING utf8)                                              AS `Agent Info - ID`, 
       IFNULL(info.tabs, '')                                                                    AS `Agent Info - TABS`, 
       IFNULL(info.type, '')                                                                    AS `Agent Info - Type`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(info_teamleader.id, '') USING utf8)                                       AS `Agent Info - Team Leader - System ID`, 
       IFNULL(info_teamleader.name_ldap, '')                                                    AS `Agent Info - Team Leader - Name`, 
       creator.id                                                                               AS `Created By - System ID`, 
       creator.name                                                                             AS `Created By - Name`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(authorizing_teamleader_user.id, '') USING utf8)                           AS `Processed By - Team Leader - System ID`, 
       IFNULL(authorizing_teamleader_user.name_ldap, '')                                        AS `Processed By - Team Leader - Name`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(authorizing_teamleader_user.emp_id, '') USING utf8)                       AS `Processed By - Team Leader - Employee ID`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(authorizing_teamleader.datetime, '%d %b %Y'), '') USING utf8) AS `Processed On - Team Leader - Date`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(authorizing_teamleader.datetime, '%h:%i %p'), '') USING utf8) AS `Processed On - Team Leader - Time`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(authorizing_manager_user.id, '') USING utf8)                              AS `Processed By - Manager - System ID`, 
       IFNULL(authorizing_manager_user.name_ldap, '')                                           AS `Processed By - Manager - Name`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(authorizing_manager_user.emp_id, '') USING utf8)                          AS `Processed By - Manager - Employee ID`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(authorizing_manager.datetime, '%d %b %Y'), '') USING utf8)    AS `Processed On - Manager - Date`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(authorizing_manager.datetime, '%h:%i %p'), '') USING utf8)    AS `Processed On - Manager - Time`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(authorizing_director_user.id, '') USING utf8)                             AS `Processed By - Director - System ID`, 
       IFNULL(authorizing_director_user.name_ldap, '')                                          AS `Processed By - Director - Name`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(authorizing_director_user.emp_id, '') USING utf8)                         AS `Processed By - Director - Employee ID`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(authorizing_director.datetime, '%d %b %Y'), '') USING utf8)   AS `Processed On - Director - Date`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(authorizing_director.datetime, '%h:%i %p'), '') USING utf8)   AS `Processed On - Director - Time`, 
       status.des                                                                               AS `Status`,
       CONVERT(IF(status.des = 'Pending', '', status_by.id) USING utf8)                         AS `Status By - System ID`, 
       IFNULL(status_by.name_ldap, '')                                                          AS `Status By - Name`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(status_by.emp_id, '') USING utf8)                                         AS `Status By - Employee ID`, 
       IFNULL(status_by_role.des, '')                                                           AS `Status By - Position`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(form.statuson, '%d %b %Y'), '') USING utf8)                   AS `Status On - Date`, 
       CONVERT(IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(form.statuson, '%h:%i %p'), '') USING utf8)                   AS `Status On - Time`, 
       CONCAT('http://cns/pdf/', form.pdf)                                                      AS `PDF` 
FROM   cns_form AS form 
       JOIN cns_departments AS department 
         ON form.deptid = department.id 
       JOIN cns_sections AS section 
         ON form.sectid = section.id
       JOIN (cns_users AS reporting_to_1, 
             cns_departments AS reporting_to_1_department)
         ON reporting_to_1.id = form.rprtid1
            AND reporting_to_1.dept_id = reporting_to_1_department.id
       LEFT JOIN (cns_users AS reporting_to_2, 
                  cns_departments AS reporting_to_2_department)
         ON reporting_to_2.id = form.rprtid2
            AND reporting_to_2.dept_id = reporting_to_2_department.id
       LEFT JOIN cns_form_attachments AS attachment_1 
         ON form.id = attachment_1.form_id 
            AND attachment_1.id = (SELECT MIN(id) 
                                   FROM   cns_form_attachments 
                                   WHERE  form_id = form.id) 
       LEFT JOIN cns_form_attachments AS attachment_2 
         ON form.id = attachment_2.form_id 
            AND attachment_2.id = (SELECT MAX(id) 
                                   FROM   cns_form_attachments 
                                   WHERE  form_id = form.id) 
       JOIN cns_status AS status 
         ON form.status = status.id
       JOIN cns_form_type AS form_type 
         ON form.waivetype = form_type.id
       LEFT JOIN (cns_form_infos AS info, 
                  cns_users AS info_teamleader)
         ON form.id = info.form_id 
            AND info_teamleader.id = info.teamleaderid
       JOIN cns_users AS creator
         ON creator.id = form.empid
       LEFT JOIN (cns_form_authorizers AS authorizing_teamleader, 
                  cns_users AS authorizing_teamleader_user)
         ON authorizing_teamleader.form = form.id
            AND authorizing_teamleader.role = 't'
            AND authorizing_teamleader_user.id = authorizing_teamleader.`from`
       LEFT JOIN (cns_form_authorizers AS authorizing_manager, 
                  cns_users AS authorizing_manager_user)
         ON authorizing_manager.form = form.id
            AND authorizing_manager.role = 'm'
            AND authorizing_manager_user.id = authorizing_manager.`from`
       LEFT JOIN (cns_form_authorizers AS authorizing_director, 
                  cns_users AS authorizing_director_user)
         ON authorizing_director.form = form.id
            AND authorizing_director.role = 'd'
            AND authorizing_director_user.id = authorizing_director.`from`
       LEFT JOIN (cns_users AS status_by, 
                  cns_roles AS status_by_role)
         ON status_by.id = form.statusby
            AND status_by.role = status_by_role.id
WHERE status.des != 'Pending'
ORDER BY form.id DESC
```

Ran `EXPLAIN` on the above query

```
+----+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id |    select_type     |            table            |  type  |           possible_keys            |      key       | key_len |                 ref                  | rows |                       Extra                        |
+----+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | form                        | ALL    | empid,rprtid1,deptid,sectid,status | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                                 |  779 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | authorizing_teamleader      | ref    | from,role                          | role           | 1       | const                                |    0 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | authorizing_teamleader_user | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.authorizing_teamleader.from |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | authorizing_manager         | ref    | from,role                          | role           | 1       | const                                |    0 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | authorizing_manager_user    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.authorizing_manager.from    |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | status                      | ALL    | PRIMARY,des                        | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                                 |    3 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | reporting_to_1              | eq_ref | PRIMARY,dept_id                    | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.form.rprtid1                |    1 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | reporting_to_2              | eq_ref | PRIMARY,dept_id                    | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.form.rprtid2                |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | reporting_to_2_department   | ALL    | PRIMARY                            | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                                 |    9 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | info                        | eq_ref | form_id_UNIQUE                     | form_id_UNIQUE | 4       | wfs-test.form.id                     |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | info_teamleader             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.info.teamleaderid           |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | creator                     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.form.empid                  |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | attachment_1                | ref    | PRIMARY,form_id                    | form_id        | 4       | wfs-test.form.id                     |    1 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | attachment_2                | ref    | PRIMARY,form_id                    | form_id        | 4       | wfs-test.form.id                     |    1 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | authorizing_director        | ref    | from,role                          | role           | 1       | const                                |    0 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | authorizing_director_user   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.authorizing_director.from   |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | status_by                   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,role                       | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.form.statusby               |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | status_by_role              | ALL    | PRIMARY                            | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                                 |    8 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | department                  | ALL    | PRIMARY                            | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                                 |    9 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | reporting_to_1_department   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.reporting_to_1.dept_id      |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | section                     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY        | 4       | wfs-test.form.sectid                 |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cns_form_attachments        | ref    | form_id                            | form_id        | 4       | wfs-test.form.id                     |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cns_form_attachments        | ref    | form_id                            | form_id        | 4       | wfs-test.form.id                     |    1 | NULL                                               |
+----+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```